# Apache2 run perl script as Directory Index

Tags: linux, perl, apache, cgi, virtualhost

I want it so when you visit https://device.my.server.com/reg  the server runs /var/www/html/reg/registrar.cgi  which is a perl script.  Right now it is just listing the contents of the directory.  I know the script works and has executable bit set for everyone.  Server is CentOS linux HTTPD 2.2.15.  I cannot use mod-redirect or rewrite, I need to do this using the core directives like I am trying below.

```
<VirtualHost device.my.server.com:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/reg
ServerName device.my.server.com
ErrorLog logs/device.my.server.com-error_log
CustomLog logs/device.my.server-access_log co
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificatekeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/device.my.server.com.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/device.my.server.com.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/chain.crt
<Directory /var/www/html/reg>
    Options ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    DirectoryIndex registrar.cgi
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    #SetHandler cgi-script
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access the `DocumentRoot` of your `VirtualHost` like this:

```
https://device.my.server.com/reg
```

when you should be accessing it like this:

```
https://device.my.server.com/
```

If you want to use the former URL, change your `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/html`.

Also make sure when you test that you use the full address specified in  your `VirtualHost` directive (i.e. `https://device.my.server.com/`, not `http://device.my.server.com/` or `https://device/`).

In my test, the following configuration executes `/var/www/html/test/foo.cgi` when I access `https://device.my.server.com/test` (obviously I have edited host/domain name):

```
<VirtualHost device.my.server.com:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName device.my.server.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key

    <Directory /var/www/html/test>
        Options ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
        DirectoryIndex foo.cgi
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You might also consider turning off indexes as an extra security measure:

```
Options -Indexes
```

This will tell Apache not to create a directory listing, even if the file specified by `DirectoryIndex` is missing.

Comment: Disabling Indexes just shows me forbidden now when accessing the URL instead of listing the contents.  The script is still not being run.

Comment: If I point the URL directly to the cgi file, it lists the text of the file instead of executing it, but if I point to a copy of the same cgi file in the cgi-bin directory, it runs it fine.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal If it displays the text of your script then it is not being executed as CGI (obviously). Have you reloaded the configuration since adding `Options ExecCGI` and `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi`?

Comment: @GreggLeventhal Also, what are the exact URLs you're using?

Comment: I switched the documentroot to /var/www/html like you said and am using "(https) device.my.server.com/reg"

Comment: @GreggLeventhal And again, have you reloaded the Apache configuration since making these changes? If your script is displayed in plain text, no matter what URL you use to access it, that means `Options ExecCGI` and `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi` are not working.

Comment: I have done service httpd restart a hundred times.  I switched the scriptalias from cgi-bin to the /reg folder which finally allows the script to be run when called directly, now I just need it to work as a directoryindex when /reg is called

Comment: I wonder why ExecCGI is not working.  Is it possible using /var/www/html as the documentroot in the virtualhost when it already is used in the main httpd.conf config is causing a problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38491/discussion-between-thissuitisblacknot-and-gregg-leventhal)

Comment: Ultimately I had some conflicting stuff in the ssl.conf file, but since I only need one host on 443, I just moved my directory block there which works.  Thanks!